# How to call an external api from codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am facing a big problem right now in developing my application. Actually there is a function developed already in one of our previous application class file. Now we want to use that function in our new application. How can we call that function in our new controller using codeIgniter.

Note: our old application is in core PHP.

old file report.class.php....in this there is a function name `get_report()`
New controller ro_manager.php.......in this there is a function `order_details()`...

I want to call `get_report()` function in `order_details()` function......i need help in this any idea.......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Codeigniter is just a framework. You can still use native php without any problem(Paths may need a little bit modification).

Just make it as a library and load it via `$this->load->library('libraryName');`

or else, you can include it in naive way. create an instantiation in the controller and use it just like any other OOP project.

[Creating codeigniter libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) The documentation includes all the procedure you will need (with examples).

Comment: How to do instantiation in controller and call that function. I know it's silly i am new to this...........can u explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see, you’re wanting to either create a library with this old function in, and load it in your CodeIgniter controllers; or just add the function in your controller as a private method if it’s to only ever be used in that controller.

Comment: I want to use get_report() function in my controller which ever is good suggest that to me........